# Issues with JSON Parsing

Tags: perl

I need to parse the json response, but i am getting issues with this code, please help me to get rid of this.

Code:

```
use strict;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use JSON qw( decode_json );
use Data::Dumper;

my $ua=LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->agent("firefox");

my $url="http://t-smos.com:8082/brand";
my $cont=&getContent($url);
my $decoded_json = decode_json( $cont );
#print Dumper $decoded_json;

print "Name: ", $decoded_json->{"name"},"\n";


sub getContent(){

    my $url1=shift;
    my $req=HTTP::Request->new("GET"=>$url1);

    $req->header("X-Service-Token" => "506ecf24abe467aa269a5d12");
    my $res=$ua->request($req);
    my $content=$res->content;
    return $content;
}
```

i am getting error..

```
Not a HASH reference in line 12. (print "Name: ", $decoded_json->{"name"},"\n";)
```

is this the problem of referencing?

Comment: Your `$cont` variable probably does not contain what you think. Print the content of your variables, that should tell you the problem. You really should have posted that information here already.

Comment: i have already tried that, its throwing an array reference and i am getting the data from dumper. i just want to print the 'name' from the json. (you can take any json data).

Comment: If it's showing you that it is an array reference, why are you treating it as a hash reference and then asking us why?

Comment: while i am trying to get the value from an array reference, its asking a hash reference to do it.

Comment: No, you are trying to use it as a hash reference. The `$foo->{'name'}` syntax is for hash refs. Its rather simple, really. if Data::Dumper says `$VAR1 = {` (note the curly bracket) then its a hash ref, if it says `$VAR1 = [` (note the bracket) then its an array ref.

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead :

```
use strict;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use JSON qw( decode_json );
use Data::Dumper;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->agent("firefox");

my $url = "http://t-smos.com:8082/brand";
my $response = $ua->get($url);
my $decoded_json = decode_json( $response->decoded_content );
print Dumper $decoded_json;
```

### NOTE

You should provide a sample output of `Dumper` if you have troubles to parse the Perl HASH.

Comment: That line `print Dumper ..` is already in his code in the question, but commented out, so presumably he already tried it.

Comment: I suspect the count is off. The error he has given is `Not a HASH reference in line 12. (print "Name: ", $decoded_json->{"name"},"\n";)`. That particular error is something you get when using a variable that is not a reference as a reference, it has nothing to do with printing to Dumper.